# Создание процедуры SQL

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте!

Никак не могу создать, казалось бы, простую процедуру, надеюсь, смогу объяснить и вы поможете... Есть две таблицы:

> `Table1(PodrazdId,DolgnostId,KolichestvoDolgn)
> Table2(NomerSotrudnika,PodrazdId,DolgnostId)`

Далее привожу фрагменты таблиц:

**Table1**

> 1, 17, 2 - т.е. в подразделении 1 с кодом должности 17 существует 2 вакансии

Но, в **Table2** такая запись:

> 130, 1, 17 - т.е. человек с кодовым номером 130 работает в 1 отделении на должности 17

Мне нужно процедуру, которая  бы показывала список возможных вакансий, т.е. в данном случае на эту должность есть ещё одно свободное место. Понятно, что айдишники сравнить в двух таблицах, но как прописать условие для KolichestvoDolgn?

Comment: и обязательно процедуру???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
DepID,
PositionID,
VacationsCount - 
(SELECT COUNT(PeopleID)
FROM TAble2 t2
WHERE
t1.PositionId  = t2.PositionID
AND
t1.DepID = t2.DepID
)
FROM Table1 t1
```

Comment: спасибо огромнейшее!!!